# excel vba to send mail from excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to send mails from excel sheet, my vba is not working

error i am getting is "object doesn't suppoer this property or method" for all getelement statement.

I have data in excel sheet like recieptent, subject, message.

code i am using is,

```
Sub Macro2()
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
URL = Selection.Value 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = 1
    .navigate URL
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Wend
End With
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = ie.document
ie.document.getElementByName(":oa").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'reciever_mail_id
ie.document.getElementById(":op").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value 'subject
ie.document.getElementById(":nq").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value 'message
ie.document.getElementById(":p0").Click 'submit button
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "mail sent"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ie.Quit
Loop
End Sub
```

*my gmail id is already logged in, so no need to sign in.
**i am beginner in VBA, need help from expert.

Comment: Are you getting any error in above code? Or you need any other help?

Comment: error i am getting is "object doesn't suppoer this property or method" for all getelement statement.

Comment: Can you use MS Outlook as well? Sending it through the interface of a website seems a bit clunky, and Outlook does provide great functionality for sending emails

Comment: no, cant use outlook

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementByName` does not exist.

You want to use `GetElementsByName` which will return an HTMLCollection rather than a simple HTMLElement.

So if there is only one element with that name write this : `ie.document.getElementsByName(":oa")(0).Value`